Drivers for a crelander laptop
Good day peeps, who knows where I could get hold of the drivers for a CRELANDER YG14 14 Inch 360 Degree Rotating Touch Screen Laptop? Anybody? Would help much please.

Starting point at providing help is knowing what Ubuntu product & release you're using. If you're using a LTS release, you have kernel stack choice (ie. newer or older kernel modules; kernel modules commonly called drivers), but what options you have available requires us to know what you're actually using.
